# How to make user input correctly

Tags: c, clion

The question is about the part of code you can see below. I have two variables `leftLimit` and `rightLimit`. Their values should strictly be from -1 to 1 (not included). Ok, I solved this problem. When the input is >= than |1| program will ask until needed value is input. But it only works when input has digital value. When input is `a` or `/` and so on, I get the end of program and nothing works. How can I fix it? How to prevent my program from non-digital input?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
double leftLimit, rightLimit;
printf("Enter the left limit: ");
scanf ("%lf", &leftLimit);
while (fabs(leftLimit)>=1) {                
    printf("\nYou typed a wrong limit, try again: ");
    scanf("%lf", &leftLimit);
}
printf("\nEnter the right limit: ");
scanf("%lf", &rightLimit);


while (fabs(rightLimit)>=1) {                 
    printf("\nYou typed a wrong limit, try again: ");
    scanf("%lf", &rightLimit);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` is ill-suited for user input.
Prefer `fgets()` possibly followed by `sscanf()` or `strtol()` or `strtod()`

```
double leftLimit;
char buffer[1000];
for (;;) {
    printf("Enter left limit: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    char *err;
    leftLimit = strtod(buffer, &err);
    if (*err != '\n') continue;
    if (fabs(leftLimit) >= 1) continue;
    break; // all ok
}
printf("Accepted left limit of %f.\n", leftLimit);
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it endlessly want me to input left limit, even if input is correct. And what does `fflush(stdout)` do?

Comment: My bad ... `*err` must be the ENTER, not `'\0'`, code corrected

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` forces the prompt above on the screen. Usually `stdout` is line-buffered and `"Enter left limit: "` does not have a newline so it might be stuck inside `stdout` buffers

Comment: but I also have a few questions about you line `if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` . I can understand more or less this part: `(!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) ` but I don't understand `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` at all. I'm just at early stage of learning C, so I would be grateful if you explained it, or at least gave me link, where i can learn about it. Sorry for the insolence, thank you.

Comment: It's just error management --- in the very unlikely event of an input error (network failure, milk spilt on keyboard, cat chew cable, ...), in which case `fgets()` returns `NULL`, exit the program rather than keep trying for ever. Some (most??) people, confidently (!!!), just skip the error validation here :)